# php post file uploader is unable to upload large files

Tags: php, post

I'm having a problem with my php file uploader. It can upload small files nicely but when i try to upload a larger file like about 8mb it doesn't work. It comes up with
File type is not permitted Which makes no sense whatsoever because the same fileformat works fine when the file is smaller.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    header("location: http://rmaltsaar.net/rfile");
    die();
}

define("UPLOAD_DIR", "uploads/");

// process file upload

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["file"])) {
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    if ($file["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>Error</p>";
    }
}
// verify the file is a PDF
$mimetype = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if(in_array($mimetype, array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'video/webm', 'text/plain', 'audio/mpeg', 'application/zip')))
    echo "<p>File type is okay</p>";
else {
    echo "<p>File type is not permitted.</p>";
    echo "<p>Redirecting back to R-FILE.</p>";
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://rmaltsaar.net/rfile">';
    exit;
}

// ensure a random filename

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$name = generateName().".$ext";
$redirect = "http://rmaltsaar.net/rfile/uploads/" . $name;

// preserve file from temporary directory
$success = move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
if (!$success) {
    echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
    exit;
}  else {
    echo "<p>Your file has been uploaded successfully!</p>";
    echo "<p>Link to the file is: <a href='http://rmaltsaar.net/rfile/uploads/" . $name . "'>http://rmaltsaar.net/rfile/uploads/" . $name . "</a></p>";
}

function generateName($max = 6) {
    $i = 0;

    $possible_keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $keys_length = strlen($possible_keys);
    $str = "";
    while($i < $max) {
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $keys_length-1);
        $str .= $possible_keys[$rand];
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}

?>
```

I've even tried changing the php.ini values and they should be fine too

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache server after changing the php.ini configuration?

Comment: I'm using nginx and i did.

Comment: Care to explain more in depth?

Comment: Just print the value of $mimetype in case of large file as I want to check if mime_content_type() is showing correct results for large files.

Comment: It doesn't display anything

Comment: Can you please put an `exit;` before finding the extension/mime for file. May be some issue before that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Try:

```
$ext = substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1);
```

Comment: still comes up with File type is not permitted

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the name/extension of the file you're attempting to upload? The comment above your file type verification hints that you're trying to upload a PDF, but 'application/pdf' isn't included in the list of acceptable file types.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mime_content_type(), use this

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

And check for possible extensions.

Comment: still comes up with File type is not permitted

Comment: Print $ext & tell me if that is showing any value. You need to change
`$mimetype = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if(in_array($mimetype, array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'video/webm', 'text/plain', 'audio/mpeg', 'application/zip')))
`
to 

`$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(in_array($ext, array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'txt', 'mpg', 'zip')))
`

Comment: It still comes up with file type not permitted and it doesn't seem to print anything. and it happens even if the file is small this time